# Find pairs in binary search tree in which sum of nodes keys is equal key

Tags: java, tree

There is a task:

> Given a binary search tree of \$n\$ nodes, find all the pair of nodes whose sum is equal to a given number \$k\$ in \$O(n)\$ time and constant space.

Please let me know if you find bugs on any data set.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main
{
    static class Node
    {
        Node(Node left, Node right, Node parent, int key)
        {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.key = key;
        }

        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node parent;

        public int key;
    }

    public static void inOrder (Node node)
    {
        if(node.left != null) inOrder(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.key);
        if(node.right != null) inOrder(node.right);
    }

    public static Node successor (Node node)
    {
        Node successor = null;
        if(node.right != null)
        {
            node = node.right;
            while(node.left != null)
            {
                node = node.left;
            }
            successor = node;
        }
        else if(node.parent != null && node.parent.left == node) successor = node.parent;
        else if(node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node)
        {
            while(node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node)
            {
                node = node.parent;
            }
            successor = node.parent;
        }
        return successor;
    }

    public static Node predeccessor(Node node)
    {
        Node predecessor = null;
        if(node.left != null)
        {
            node = node.left;
            while(node.right != null)
            {
                node = node.right;
            }
            predecessor = node;
        }
        else if(node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node) predecessor = node.parent;
        else if(node.parent != null && node.parent.left == node)
        {
            while(node.parent != null && node.parent.left == node)
            {
                node = node.parent;
            }
            predecessor = node.parent;
        }

        return predecessor;
    }

    public static Node min (Node node)
    {
        while(node.left != null) node = node.left;
        return node;
    }

    public static Node max (Node node)
    {
        while(node.right != null) node = node.right;
        return node;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Node root = new Node(null, null, null, 5);//      5
        Node a = new Node(null, null, null, 2);   //     / \
        Node b = new Node(null, null, null, 1);   //    2   8
        Node c = new Node(null, null, null, 3);   //   /\    \
        Node d = new Node(null, null, null, 8);   //  1  3    9
        Node e = new Node(null, null, null, 9);   //

        root.left = a;
        root.right = d;
        a.parent = root;
        d.parent = root;

        a.left = b;
        a.right = c;
        b.parent = a;
        c.parent = a;

        d.right = e;
        e.parent = d;

        int sum = 10;

        //find pairs in Binary Search Tree in which sum of nodes keys is equal 10

        Node minnode = min(root);
        Node maxnode = max(root);
        while(minnode.key <= maxnode.key && minnode != maxnode)
        {
            if (minnode.key + maxnode.key == sum)
            {
                System.out.println("Pair found: " + minnode.key + " " + maxnode.key);
                minnode = successor(minnode);
                maxnode = predeccessor(maxnode);
            }
            else if(minnode.key + maxnode.key < sum)
            {
                minnode = successor(minnode);
            }
            else
            {
                maxnode = predeccessor(maxnode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: You seem to have to accounts; please [request they are merged](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

I just have minor nitpicks.

**1**

You can simplify the methods for computing a successor/predecessor:

```
public static Node successor(Node node) {
    if (node.right != null) {
        return min(node.right);
    }

    while (node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node) {
        node = node.parent;
    }

    return node.parent;
}
```

Also, you compute the `min(node.right)` above in code; hence, you repeated yourself.

**2**

I would rip off the implementation of your sum pair algorithm out of `main()`.

**3**

I would have a class, say, `NodePair`, which simply stores a pair of nodes.

**4**

The actual algorithm could just return the list of those `NodePair` objects.

**5**

Since you are printing the results, you could override `toString()` in `NodePair` and make it return a string in the format that meets your needs.

**6**

`inOrder` is not used. In case you don't need it either, consider removing it.

**7**

You import **`java.lang`**, yet you don't need to: it is imported by default. Also, you left hanging around two packages (**`java.util`** and **`java.io`**), remove them. Finally, I would encourage avoiding wildcard imports: import on individual basis, let people see what classes you use in your source.

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

    static class Node {

        Node(Node left, Node right, Node parent, int key) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.key = key;
        }

        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node parent;

        public int key;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder("Node ").append(key).toString();
        }
    }

    public static Node successor(Node node) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return min(node.right);
        }

        while (node.parent != null && node.parent.right == node) {
            node = node.parent;
        }

        return node.parent;
    }

    public static Node predeccessor(Node node) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            return max(node.left);
        }

        while (node.parent != null && node.parent.left == node) {
            node = node.parent;
        }

        return node.parent;
    }

    public static Node min(Node node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
            node = node.left;
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static Node max(Node node) {
        while (node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;
        }

        return node;
    }

    public static final class NodePair {
        public Node node1;
        public Node node2;

        public NodePair(Node node1, Node node2) {
            this.node1 = node1;
            this.node2 = node2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder("[").append(node1)
                                         .append(", ")
                                         .append(node2)
                                         .append("]")
                                         .toString();
        }
    }

    public static List<NodePair> findPairsWithSum(Node root, int sum) {
        List<NodePair> nodePairList = new ArrayList<>();
        Node minnode = min(root);
        Node maxnode = max(root);

        while (minnode.key <= maxnode.key && minnode != maxnode) {
            if (minnode.key + maxnode.key == sum) {
                nodePairList.add(new NodePair(minnode, maxnode));
                minnode = successor(minnode);
                maxnode = predeccessor(maxnode);
            } else if (minnode.key + maxnode.key < sum) {
                minnode = successor(minnode);
            } else {
                maxnode = predeccessor(maxnode);
            }
        }

        return nodePairList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Node root = new Node(null, null, null, 5);//      5
        Node a = new Node(null, null, null, 2);   //     / \
        Node b = new Node(null, null, null, 1);   //    2   8
        Node c = new Node(null, null, null, 3);   //   /\    \
        Node d = new Node(null, null, null, 8);   //  1  3    9
        Node e = new Node(null, null, null, 9);   //

        root.left = a;
        root.right = d;
        a.parent = root;
        d.parent = root;

        a.left = b;
        a.right = c;
        b.parent = a;
        c.parent = a;

        d.right = e;
        e.parent = d;

        // Print all the node pairs summing to 10.
        for (NodePair pair : findPairsWithSum(root, 10)) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

Actually, what comes to printing the node pairs, I realized that it makes sense to override **`Node.toString()`** as well. After that, building a string representation of a **`NodePair`** simplifies a bit. Please, for details refer to **`Node.toString`** and **`NodePair.toString`**.